# Can’t submit file for Facebook App Approval

Tags: facebook

I’ll set my outrage with the way this process works (to whom can I speak?) aside for the moment: we are attempting to provide FB with a link to our ~200 mb app for approval. We have been rejected 3 times because they are incapable of extracting our zip file (they request a zip for some unknown reason — it has minimal size impact).

Some detail: we are linking to the zip on our Dropbox. We have removed all punctuation from our app title (Pandamonium!.app becomes Pandamonium.app). We have eliminated spaces from our source folder. I thought all these could be causing a problem with iOS-sim.

I’m not sure what is left to do, but I am hoping someone can present a clear set of instructions (NOT THEIR INSTRUCTIONS, WHICH I HAVE READ) they have followed particularly if you have met similar snags or ANY ideas for resolution. All they send me is useless screenshots of their simulator unable to open the app which I have simulated and opened successfully daily with iOS-sim for the last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a great deal of trial and error I found that using Facebook's command-line instructions was what was causing the issue. You should just compress your .app file in an ordinary fashion (right click and compress -- I used a Windows computer just to make sure everything was copasetic after reading about bizarre Mac .cbgz compression issues).

Regardless, in summary, I can now see why no one else has had an issue with this: it's because no one reads their instructions and rather just creates their .zip files in the ordinary way; unsurprisingly, you're better off using your common sense rather than listening to others.

Aside: ironically, after being told my use case was fine and the only issue was not being able to unzip, Facebook (India) has now told me they couldn't find my login button (which is gigantic, in multiple places, and clearly described in my instructions). This process is an absolute joke. I wish anyone going through this hell good luck.